# How can we search for webpages with video embeds?

Tags: google-search

Is there any way to use Google to search for webpages with video embeds?

For example, I would like to search for all pages in movies.stackexchange.com that has a video embedded. E.g. `site:movies.stackexchange.com has:video`.